# Stackoverflow Exception raising only without Visual Studio

Tags: multithreading, stack-overflow

I have a difficult WPF application, which works with PTL, many third-party libraries and network. In developer workstation it works fine (in release mode too), but when I run it in client workstation - I got stackoverflow exception in same input data. Also app crashed always in different places.

So, my questions are:

1. I know, that its impossible to catch stackoverflow exception by try-catch-finally. But may be exists any workaround to understand which module generate this problem?
2. What different between client and developer environment, if all third-party libraries are equals?

Answer (score 0):

> I know, that its impossible to catch a `StackOverflowError` exception using try-catch-finally.

It is not impossible.  Just highly inadvisable, and it probably won't fix the issue.  (The best a handler could do would be to abandon what ever caused the problem and try to continue.  But what if the application *needed* the result that was being computed?  Or what if the application tries the same computation again?)

> But may be exists any workaround to understand which module generate this problem?

Without knowing the real cause of the problem, there is no good workaround.

How do you find the real cause of the problem?  Debug the application!

---

> What different between client and developer environment, if all third-party libraries are equals?

In general it could be any of the following:

- Different Java versions
- Different OS versions
- Containers and/or virtualization
- Different networking environments
- Different external tools installed
- Different file system layouts
- Different users or file permissions
- Different Java application configs
- Different input data / databases.

and probably a few more besides.  In short there are *potentially* lots of things that could be different that *could* cause different behaviors.  You *might* be able to discount some of these as not relevant, but it is also possible to be wrong about that.

IMO, looking for the differences is the wrong approach.  A better idea is to **debug** your application in the client environment.  Read the stacktrace, read the code, attach a debugger to the JVM and set breakpoints, etc to try and find out what is actually happening.